# How do I get the Paladin charger if I'm a Blood Elf Paladin?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a mount as a paladin?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/how-do-i-get-a-mount-as-a-paladin)

I've finally reached level 20 and I'm trying to get a horse. I went to my Paladin riding trainer near Silvermoon City. But when  I clicked on him, there was nothing?

How do I get the Paladin charger if I'm a Blood Elf Paladin?

Comment: You need apprentice training first before the spell will show up with your paladin trainer AFAIK.

Comment: you do not need apprentice training - you get first stage of riding for free when you train summon horse

Comment: @perspektiv Hence my answer ;)

Comment: I was just going to say that Mark :). The question is slightly different, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Paladins get Apprentice Riding for free so you do not need to visit a Riding Trainer. Instead, you need to go see your Paladin Trainer, such as [Champion Bachi](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=16681) in Silvermoon City, to learn [Summon Warhorse](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=34769).